# Adding a external library to my xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, libraries

How do I add an external library to my xcode project?
Currently I'm trying to add this [camera library](https://github.com/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera) , and I thought it was just about adding the pod and installing it but when I try to add the import LLSimpleCamera I get no such module "LLSimpleCamera".

Any help?

Comment: Can you show any screenshots your xcode project or some code. There could be several issues. Something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/nqaTz.png

Comment: Add some code that you have tried ??

Comment: @Asdrubal http://imgur.com/nJWAyiB

Comment: @JoseDeJesusAlarconMontoya can you upload your podfile?

Comment: im following this example https://github.com/strawb3rryx7/LLSimpleCamera-Swift-Example

Comment: @Asdrubal http://imgur.com/mH2m8jT

Answer (score -1):

Could you be opening Animal-Spotting.xcodeproject file instead of Animal-Spotting.xcodeworkspace?

You could always try the classic "clean build & delete the derived data"

Comment: im using the workspace and ill try the clean build & delete the derived data Thanks mate

Comment: i did the clean build thing but the issue its still there